# Converting large GeoJSON to shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson, large-datasets

I have recently downloaded a building footprint GeoJSON file from Microsoft Bing Maps. The file I downloaded was for the entirety of Texas, and is of approximately 2.2 GB file size. They do not provide the data in any smaller sections for the state of Texas.

My issue is that I am unable to convert this GeoJSON into any usable format, such as a shapefile. I have tried to use https://mapshaper.org/ but my file size is too large and the website crashes. Similarly, I have tried to open the GeoJSON in QGIS, but that program crashes as well. I know ArcGIS has the Data Interoperability Toolset, but that requires a special license.

Does anyone have any other techniques to convert a large GeoJSON file?

Comment: You know that these are already in Shapefile Format here? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Microsoft_Building_Footprint_Data  Example > Texas direct download https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqWv0F0N63JkgSxCOnhjhJGlsVHx

Comment: personally I'd say [don't use shapefiles](http://switchfromshapefile.org/), and not in favor of GeoJSON (or at least not in an OGC aware environment). note that e.g. due to interoperability concerns, 2GB should be the working size maximum (not the technical limit, though). QGIS comes shipped with the core GDAL/OGR (terminal) functions; if you like to give it a try, *ogr2ogr* can do some magic to your file, including splitting it into multiple files and format conversion.

Comment: @ThingumaBob They stated in the question that QGIS crashes when trying to load the geojson file. Is it possible to use ogr2ogr to split the geojson without first loading it into QGIS? If so, that would be helpful if you posted it as an answer.

Comment: @csk oh it is, *ogr2ogr* is run from the terminal and doesn't need QGIS...the other way around maybe. but while writing the answer I tried my script on a generated 2.5GB file (~25M rows) and was struck by failure: the driver doesn't read the file in chunks properly, even with `-gt` option set, and *ogr2ogr* killed itself due to memory overhead. I *did* convert ~1.9GB files on a much larger machine than my laptop, but this might not be practical then. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/16357/93656) however, was gold.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the help! @ThingumaBob, the link to the python script was perfect, I was able to split the geojson into 4 parts and then separately convert them all to shapefiles in QGIS.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing (break apart Microsoft building footprint data for Texas), and having issues. I was wondering if there was any way you would be willing to share your 4 split shapefiles?

Answer (score 5):

Shapefile have a size limit of 2GB so trying to convert your 2.2GB geojson probably result in a too big shapefile.

You should try to load it in a database that is capable of handling that amount of data (a simple spatialite database for exemple could be created and managed from qgis and has no size limit)

Also for large file you may run to hardware limitation....

Comment: A lot depends on the attributes, but I wouldn't expect a 2.2Gb GeoJSON to exceed 1Gb in shapefile.

Comment: Those building footprints do not contain any attributes at all. Conversion with something like `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" texas.shp texas.geojson` should work.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/woodb/geojsplit works for me.

node --max-old-space-size=20480 /usr/lib/node_modules/geojsplit/bin/geojsplit -a 1 -l 3000000 -v -o ~/data ~/data/California.geojson

I have divided California.geojson into four files with max 3000000 features per each.

By default, node has only 512 Mb memory limit, so --max-old-space-size=20480 increase it to 20Gb

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL NODE FIRST -- **https://www.guru99.com/download-install-node-js.html**

OPEN powershell install $geojsplit
PS c:\users\rakesh>$geojsplit

and now go to your geojson file location and run this script

PS D:\Florida>node --max-old-space-size=500 C:\Users\rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geojsplit\bin\geojsplit -a 1 -l 30000 -v -o k D:/florida/florida.geojson