# How to split large GeoJSON in small chunks

Tags: python, geojson

I am trying to split Microsoft building data for Pakistan. It's size is 6gb. I am trying to use geojsplit to split the large GeoJSON file into small chunks, but it giving me this erro:

> File "C:\Users\waqas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ijson\backends\python.py", line 171, in basic_parse
> raise common.JSONError('Additional data')
> ijson.common.JSONError: Additional data

Any other way to split GeoJSON file?

Comment: If your JSON is not valid, you won't be able to split it into logical chunks. Try to manually split the file as plain text, then fix/remove the feature that was cut in half and try your splitting process on the bisected file again. This way you might be able to find the broken feature(s) and fix them in the full file so that you can geojsplit that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your **GeoJSON is invalid**. As this is rather large file, please validate it offline by running [GeoJSON lint](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojsonlint.com) on your infrastructure.

After you correct the GeoJSON there are couple of ideas about splitting it:

1. Splitting [GeoJSON using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371828/splitting-up-geojson-into-multiple-shapefiles-using-qgis).
2. Splitting [JSON using FME](https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q000080hevvSAA/split-json-into-several-features).
3. Splitting [GeoJSON in shell/bash](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/16357/72712).
4. Splitting [GeoJSON using python](https://medium.com/@underchemist/splitting-geojson-files-using-geojsplit-8ff72ec68c67):

For dividing GeoJSON file with python to 10000 features per feature collection type in terminal/your IDE:

```
pip install geojsplit
geojsplit --geometry-count 10000 ~/data/large.geojson
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem using Git. Simply download Git from chrome and use this command to split files. Open Git terminal in folder where you already keep your file.

```
#Commond
split myLargeFile.geojsonl -l 1000000
```